# Not able to delete the registry entry through golang

Tags: go, registry

I wrote a code in golang to delete a key from the registry entry and my code is as below.

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`, registry.ALL_ACCESS)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR::<Uninstall> Error in getting the registry values: ",err)
        }
        defer k.Close()

        err=k.DeleteValue("MyKey")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR::<Uninstall> Error occured while deleting the MyKey Details From the registry ",err)
        }
```

And my output is as below

```
2016/02/18 13:51:40 ERROR::<Uninstall> Error occured while deleting the MyKey Details From the registry  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the error message is telling.

Comment: I have a key there with that name. All i have to do is just delete the key. But what i have used will delete the value but i am not sure whether it can delete a key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [registry.DeleteKey](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry#DeleteKey) which is defined in the following way:

```
func DeleteKey(k Key, path string) error
```

> `DeleteKey` deletes the subkey path of key k and its values.

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`, registry.ALL_ACCESS)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer k.Close()

err := registry.DeleteKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services`)    
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: 2016/02/18 15:35:58 ERROR::<Uninstall> Error in Deleting the myKey registry values::  Access is denied. but i ran the exe with administrator privilege only.

Comment: This is another question, which is not strictly related to your original question. Maybe this help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get anything of this to work, so I used PowerShell instead. Here is my function:

```
import("github.com/KnicKnic/go-powershell/pkg/powershell")

...


func delreg(service string) {
    reg := `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\` + service
    color.Warn.Println("Will delete: " + reg)

    runspace := powershell.CreateRunspaceSimple()
    defer runspace.Close()
    GetService := (`Remove-Item -Path "` + reg + `" -Recurse`)
    results1 := runspace.ExecScript(GetService, false, nil)
    results1.Close()
}
```